# USB OTG on Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

Does anyone know if the Project Tango tablet supports USB OTG? Or alternatively if the USB 3.0 port on the dock can act as an OTG hub? Online it only states that these ports are for charging so I am unsure if OTG functionality is also included. It would certainly increase the usefulness of the Tango's tracking capabilities if it was also able to interface with other devices.

Answer (score 1):

Tango device supports "USB 3.0 host via dock connector". It means that it is possible to connect external device USB, but setup requires additional source of power.
Please refer official web site:
https://www.google.com/atap/project-tango/hardware/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The Project Tango tablet support USB OTG, you could interface to other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking the Tango tablet with an app named "USB OTG Checker".  It says that the USB OTG API is loaded, and I can browse a USB memory drive attached to the dock's USB 3.0 port.

The USB OTG Checker says that the Tango tablet fails the check for USB OTG Signal, but I think this is because I'm not attaching a true external data source, like a USB Hard Drive.

Comment: The OTG checker is looking for a certain pair of pins to be shorted/switched signaling a data connection and potential power draw for the tablet's USB stack to go into "host mode". If you use an OTG enabled USB hub or a microUSB to USB-A cable it should show as OTG enabled if an OTG device is attached. I should be able to test this once my Tango tablet shows up this week.